# In R how do you change a character vector into the ASCII code equivalent?

Tags: r

I came up with this:

```
as.numeric(charToRaw("ABC"))
[1] 65 66 67
```

Is there an R function to do this?

Comment: I meant a single R function like ord("A") outputs 65.

Comment: utf8ToInt("ABC") is the answer.  Thanks!